# Get File Content from Azure File Storage and special characters

Tags: azure, file, azure-logic-apps, azure-files

I try to read a csv file in a Logic App from Azure File Storage with Get File Content .
The file contains strings with special characters like "æ" and any other danish characters.
The result is in the image :
[image]

Do you have a solution how can I display those special characters?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish this, you must first implement base64 encoding to non-Unicode text to transform it to the utf-8 format and then using Azure Functions generate any.NET-supported encoding to UTF-8.Follow is the piece of code that I took from this [MSFT - Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/support-non-unicode-character-encoding#azure-functions-version).

> ````
> string requestBody = new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEnd();
>     dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
>
>     if (data == null || data.text == null || data.encodingInput == null || data.encodingOutput == null) {
>       return new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass text/encodingOutput properties in the input JSON object.");
>     }
>
>     Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
>
>     try {
>       string encodingInput = data.encodingInput.Value;
>       inputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(name: encodingInput);
>     } catch (ArgumentException) {
>       return new BadRequestObjectResult($"Input character set value '{data.encodingInput.Value}' is not supported. Supported values are
> listed at
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx.");
>     }
>
>     Encoding encodingOutput = null;
>     try {
>       string outputEncoding = data.encodingOutput.Value;
>       encodingOutput = Encoding.GetEncoding(outputEncoding);
>     } catch (ArgumentException) {
>       return new BadRequestObjectResult($"Output character set value '{data.encodingOutput.Value}' is not supported. Supported values are
> listed at
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx.");
>     }
>
>     return (ActionResult) new JsonResult(
>       value: new {
>         text = Convert.ToBase64String(
>           Encoding.Convert(
>             srcEncoding: inputEncoding,
>             dstEncoding: encodingOutput,
>             bytes: Convert.FromBase64String((string) data.text)))
>       });   } } ```
> ````

for more information please refer [Support non-Unicode character encoding in Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/support-non-unicode-character-encoding).

Comment: Thanks for the answer .I solved it .I set Infer Content type to No ...I've made the conversion function as you said in answer and the  I called with Body like this: 
{
  "encodingInput": "windows-1252",
  "encodingOutput": "utf-8",
  "text": @{body('Read_file_content')['$content']}- this is the content of the file 
}